# Computed Properties and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

I have a problem with query linq.

I have this classes:

```
public abstract class Subject : IValidatableObject
{
    public abstract string FullName { get; }

    public abstract SubjectType SubjectType { get; }

    public string FiscalIdentifier => String.IsNullOrEmpty(VatNumber) ? FiscalCode : VatNumber;
}

[Table("Person")]
public partial class Person : Subject
{
    public override string FullName => FirstName + " " + LastName;

    public override SubjectType SubjectType => SubjectType.Person;

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}


[Table("Corporation")]
public partial class Corporation : Subject
{
    public override string FullName => Name;

    public override SubjectType SubjectType => SubjectType.Corporation;

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When lunch this query

```
 IQuerable<Subject> result = GetList()
   .OrderBy(s => s.FullName)
   .Skip(start)
   .Take(length)
   .ToList();
```

The Framework display this error: "Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported"

I have also tried to use these libraries but lunch Exception:

**DelegateDecompiler**: 'Unable to cast the type 'OneData.DataModel.Subject' to type 'OneData.DataModel.Person'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

```
public abstract class Subject : IValidatableObject
{
    [Computed]
    public abstract string FullName { get; }

    [Computed]
    public abstract SubjectType SubjectType { get; }

    [Computed]
    public string FiscalIdentifier => String.IsNullOrEmpty(VatNumber) ? FiscalCode : VatNumber;
}

 IQuerable<Subject> result = GetList()
   .OrderBy(s => s.FullName)
   .Skip(start)
   .Take(length)
   .Decompile()
   .ToList();
```

**Linq.Translations**: An item with the same key has already been added.

```
public partial class Person : Subject
{
    private static readonly CompiledExpression<Person, string> FullNameExpression
        = DefaultTranslationOf<Person>.Property(e => e.FullName).Is(e => e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName);

    public override string FullName => FullNameExpression.Evaluate(this);
}


public partial class Corporation : Subject
{
    private static readonly CompiledExpression<Corporation, string> FullNameExpression
        = DefaultTranslationOf<Corporation>.Property(e => e.FullName).Is(e => e.Name);

    public override string FullName => FullNameExpression.Evaluate(this);
}
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Fabrizio

Comment: Use the `[NotMapped]` annotations to ensure that EF doesn't try to map computed properties.

Comment: Please show your efforts with the libraries you mention. It's not clear why they don't work in your case. Which EF version is this? Please add the applicable tag.

Comment: What you want to try can you please eloborate

Comment: I want to sql paginate to reduce record saved in memory (don't use ToList before pagination)

Comment: I use EntityFramework 6.2

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the best approach is to have a separate DTO classes that you only use to communicate with database, these classes will only have the properties that you want to keep in the db. Within your business logic you use a different class. This might seem as duplicity but makes your code much more flexible and maintainable.

```
// Use for database
[Table("Person")]
public class PersonDto
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

// Use in business logic 
public partial class Person : Subject
{
    public override string FullName => FirstName + " " + LastName;

    public override SubjectType SubjectType => SubjectType.Person;

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: It's common practice to use plain entity names for the persistence model classes and pre- or suffixes for related business/view models.

Comment: Thanks for replay, but my problem is to sort subjects by "FullName" to paginate query result.

Comment: @Fabrizio you should still be able to do something like this to get the result you need: `var result = _context.Person.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).ThenBy(x => x.LastName).Skip(10).Take(10);`

Comment: @Immugio I can not use your query,  I need the list of subjects and therefore both people and corporations